# Cleartool: How to apply label to files which are in my current view only?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I could not find the proper command to apply a label to files which are in my current view. I have tried the following command:

```
cleartool mklabel -r TEST_LABEL /vob/test/a
```

However, the problem is that this command will apply the "`Test_Label`" label to every files in the "`vob/test/a`" directories regardless of whether the files are in my current view.
Is there any command to apply label only to the files listed in my current view?

Answer (score 5):

```
cleartool mklabel  -r(ecurse) LABEL_NAME <directory name>
```

This command will apply LABEL_NAME to all files in folder and below of your view, you can just go to that directory,then type following command to create and apply label

```
> cd /vob/test/a
> cleartool mklbtype –nc TEST_LABEL 
> cleartool mklabel  -r TEST_LABEL .
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`mklabel` documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm?lang=en) state states, as to what version is labeled:

> Processes the entire subtree of each pname that is a directory element (including pname itself). VOB symbolic links are not traversed during the recursive descent into the subtree.

One example mentions:

> Attach that label to the **version of the current directory selected by your view**, and to the **currently selected version of each element in and below the current directory**.

---

Now, if you want to be *really* sure of the versions actually labelled, one solution is to use a `find` command, combined with your `mklabel`:

```
cleartool find . -cview -exec "cleartool mklabel TEST_LABEL \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

If you had already that label applied to incorrect version and want to move it:

```
cleartool find . -cview -exec "cleartool mklabel -replace TEST_LABEL \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

That way, you can first *list* the versions involved:

```
cleartool find . -cview -print
```

And then, if you agree with the output, apply the `mklabel` through the `-exec` directive.

The [OP user1096966](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1096966/user1096966) reports making it work with a [`cleartool ls`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ls.htm?resultof=%22version%22%20%22selector%22), to be sure to select only element ***visible*** in the current view:

```
cleartool ls -r -vis
```

The is no '-exec' directive, so a pipe might be involved, as in (not tested, but you get the idea):

```
cleartool ls -r -vis -s -nxn | xargs cleartool mklabel -replace TEST_LABEL
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your respond but I would like to apply(mklabel) label and not create(mklbtype) a new label.

Comment: I have just tried "cleartool find . -cview -print" but the output is not what I want. The output displayed other directory that is not visible in my current view. Thanks for your help, I will try to get the correct output first.

Comment: I managed to get my desired output if I use this command "cleartool ls -r -vis"

Comment: @user1096966: did you try `cleartool find . -cview -vis -exec...`, because you cannot add the `-exec` to a `ls`.

Comment: Yes, I cannot use `exec` if I use `ls`, but I cannot use `cleartool find . -cview -vis` too.

Answer (score 0):

The doco is really clear about what is being labelled, in fact the first example shown in doco states that exactly...current view objects are labelled by default & currently selected versions (i.e. if in your view then label it, else not.)

....extract below from doco below (note: context and command and that label-type-selector pname is the last parameter...left blank below because resident in working dir)...

Example:
•Create a label type named REL6. ***Attach that label to the version of the current directory selected by your view, and to the currently selected version of each element in and below the current directory.*** 
cmd-context>  mklbtype –nc REL6

Regards

Jim2