# Labelling files with spaces in ClearCase

Tags: clearcase, labeling

We have a script that labels files recursively.  Here is the command that executes the label command.

```
cleartool ls -recurse -vob_only -visible -short | \
    xargs cleartool mklabel -replace -follow VPCEUM_9.0.0.99 > label.txt 2>&1
```

When is encounter files with spaces the name such as `/directory/d1/my file is here.doc`, the command errors off.

How do I get ClearCase/unix to accept the space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tow approaches with [`cleartool mklabel`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm):

- you can use mklabel directly, with the `-recurse` option.
  That will label all the files (with or without space) for you. But that can label files that are not in your current view.

  ```
   cleartool mklabel -recurse -replace -follow VPCEUM_9.0.0.99
  ```
- Or, as I mentioned in "[Cleartool: How to apply label to files which are in my current view only?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8500379/6309)", you use cleartool find:

  ```
  # Windows syntax
  cleartool find . -cview -exec "cleartool mklabel -replace TEST_LABEL \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""

  # Unix syntax
  cleartool find . -cview -exec 'cleartool mklabel -replace TEST_LABEL "$CLEARCASE_XPN"'
  ```

The `"$CLEARCASE_XPN"` part allows you to label files with spaces.

Comment: I’m trying to run the cleartool find and mklabel commands on windows using Perl but the spaces problems is not solved, Any idea what should be the syntax ?
      system(" cleartool find V:\\$VIEW\\$VOB -cview -version {!lbtype($LABEL)} -exec \"cleartool mklabel -replace $LABEL %CLEARCASE_XPN%\" ");

Comment: @Elad that is a good question, that you could ask separately. I'll keep looking in the meantime.