# Clearcase Command for labeling Fails

Tags: unix, version-control, label, clearcase, vob

We are applying labels recursively to a VOB.

Following clearcase command is failing and in turn the process of labelling a whole vob is failing.
To be honest, I am not aware of what every word means in this command.
Can you please explain what it does so that i could figure out why the process of labeling is failing.

Also I have attached the error code it's throwing:

```
cleartool ls -recurse -vob_only -visible -short | xargs cleartool mklabel -replace -follow <label_name>
ERROR CODE:     256
```

Answer (score 1):

[`cleartool mklabel`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-41&lang=en) is applied to each element returned by [`cleartool ls`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_ls.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-23&lang=en), restricting the listing to objects in the VOB storage, and visible to the operating system listing command.

However, a `cleartool mklabel -replace` (which moves an existing label if found) means you must have the right to modify that label, or be element owner.

Try first the `mklabel` command in isolation on a single file before using it in an xargs pipe.

Try also [an alternative syntax I proposed before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25982827/6309):

```
# Windows syntax
cleartool find . -cview -exec "cleartool mklabel -replace TEST_LABEL \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""

# Unix syntax
cleartool find . -cview -exec 'cleartool mklabel -replace TEST_LABEL "$CLEARCASE_XPN"'
```

---

The OP adds:

> The weird thing is that from the logs labeling seems successful for all the files. (`Created label "label_name" on "filepath" version "/main/3"`.)
>
> But when it exits it throws this error:

```
Process Create Label Lock for label_name in the VOB: vob_1 
Label label_name has been locked 
Process Create Label Lock for label_name in the VOB: vob_2 
Label label_name has been locked 
LABELING FAILED 
Flag created: /user/msatcmsvn/build_artifacts/label_name_LABEL.FLAG
```

It depends if the label was applied to an element in vob1, 2 or another vob.
Generally, this message is linked to a [global type locked](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_typeadm_lock.htm) or to the lbtype locked in vob1 and two.

A `cleartool lslock lbtype:LABELNAME@\vob1` (or `@/vobs/vob1`) on Unix, as well as a `cleartool descr -l lbtype:LABELNAME@\vob1` can help see the issue.

Comment: Thanks for an explanatory answer. However, issue is not with the rights. The weird thing is that from the logs labeling seems successful for all the files. (Created label "label_name" on "filepath" version "/main/3".) But when it exits it throws this error: 
1)Process Create Label Lock for label_name in the VOB: vob_1

2)Label label_name has been locked

3)Process Create Label Lock for label_name in the VOB: vob_2

4)Label label_name has been locked

5)LABELING FAILED

6)Flag created: /user/msatcmsvn/build_artifacts/label_name_LABEL.FLAG