# How do I handle shell metacharacters inside of a ClearCase -exec command string?

Tags: clearcase, quotes

## Background

I am trying to update all files with label LABEL_A to have the label LABEL_B.  Right now I am attempting a find command as shown below:

```
ct find . -version 'lbtype (LABEL_A)' -exec 'cleartool mklabel (LABEL_B) $CLEARCASE_XPN'
```

When I enter said command, the following error is returned:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `cleartool mklabel (LABEL_B) $CLEARCASE_XPN'
```

## What the Documentation says

When I enter `ct man query_language`, the following is stated about mklabel:

> Attach the label EYY6 to the version of test.c that is already
>      labeled EYY5.
>
> UNIX and Linux:
>
> `cleartool mklabel -ver '{lbtype(EYY5)}' EYY6 test.c`
>       Created label "EYY6" on "test.c" version "/main/4".

However, the above documentation is the case for *one specific file* my case is looking at *all files* with an old label. This prompted my question

## Question

What is the proper quoting for the argument of `mklabel` when attempting to update all files of specific label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find example of quoting policy in "[`CLEARCASE_XPN` not parsed as variable in ClearCase command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11429466/6309)" (2012)

But you also have the [`cleartool mklabel`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm) syntax itself to consider: there is no `(xxx)` parenthesis needed:

```
 ct find . -version 'lbtype(LABEL_A)' -exec 'cleartool mklabel LABEL_B "$CLEARCASE_XPN"'
```

And no space after `lbtype` and its opening `(`.
See examples in

- "[Labelling files with spaces in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25982827/6309)" (2014)
- "[How to retrieve the list of files modified across base lines in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10527967/6309)" (also 2012).
- "[`cleartool find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm)" (Example section)

> ```
> label type "(LABEL_B)" not found in VOB "/vobs/le_vob"
> ```

Again: no `()` should be used.
That means you need to create the label *type* first in that vob:
(see "[Create label with ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25913734/6309)")

```
cleartool mklbtype -global -nc lbtype:LABEL_B@/vobs/le_vob
```

Then try again the original `find - exec mklabel` command.

Comment: This results in the identical error that I encountered from @paulsm4's answer: `cleartool: Error: label type "(LABEL_B)" not found in VOB "/vobs/le_vob" and no global type definition can be found.` and c`leartool: Error: Unable to create label "(LABEL_B)" on "./common/cord_sup/src/header.h" version "/main/dev/super_dev/3"`

Comment: @isakbob I have edited my answer. Why use () around the label name though?

Comment: is it against convention to use "()" around label names?

Comment: @isakbob in the context of mklabel, that would not be correctly interpreted. In the context of a search parameter like `lbtype`, it is useful.

Answer (score -1):

I think your question is *Actually*:

Q: How do I handle shell metacharacters inside of a ClearCase `-exec` command string?

A: Try this:

```
ct find . -version 'lbtype (LABEL_A)' -exec 'cleartool mklabel \(LABEL_B\) $CLEARCASE_XPN'
```

NOTE:

You might need to escape the "$" in "$CLEARCASE_XPN", too.  It depends on whether Clearcase is expecting the literal "$CLEARCASE_XPN", or the expanded shell value.

Comment: If I try the method in your answer I get `cleartool: error: Pathname not found "$CLEARCASE_XPN".`   If I try the method you suggest afterward (with a "\" before the "S"), I get `cleartool: Error: label type "(LABEL_B)" not found in VOB "/vobs/le_vob" and no global type definition can be found.` and
`cleartool: Error: Unable to create label "(LABEL_B)" on "./common/cord_sup/src/header.h" version "/main/dev/super_dev/3"`